Binding DataGridCell content to Textbox in Customized ToolTip WPF
I have datagrid control in my project and i want to add tooltip to datagridcells. I customized the tooltip control and put a textbox control in it. I tried to bind cell content value to textbox but it did not work.
When I use the Tooltip contol directly (without customizing) it is worked.
This is xaml code:
Without customizing the tooltip binding is working.
 <Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}"/>          
            </Style>
</Window.Resources>
     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
               AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

But customized tooltip binding is not working.
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        
       
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
               AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

This is model class:
public class Person
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

This is ViewModel class:
public class MainViewVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public MainViewVM()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person()
            {
                PersonName = "Andrei",
                Surname = "Surname 1"

            },

            new Person()
            {
                PersonName = "Jack",
                Surname = "Surname 2"

            },


            new Person()
            {
                PersonName = "Melisa",
                Surname = "Surname 3"

            }
        };
    }
   

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}



RelativeSource Self will be different when used inside cell (1) or inside TextBox (2). Not sure to what should Content.Text refer without full [mcve], but I guess you need to find cell again from TextBox with {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}.

@Sinatr thanx. I change Relative Source as you stated but it did not work.  i guess i should changed Path also. I want to refer cell value. How can i do that?

Cell value? DataContext? The TextBox should inherit it, try <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>.

Actually no, TextBox will not inherit it and accessing DataContext may need more work via PlacementTarget.

It would likely take few minutes to make [mcve] working. Or let us continue and compile code in our heads: <TextBox Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToolTip}}"/> shall we? =D

I added more codes.

You need to do something like this:
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ToolTip>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToolTip}}" />
            </ToolTip>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

I have to include ToolTip to access its PlacementTarget.
DataContext return us Person instance (you can override ToString  or use data template to see its properties in tooltip). Use Content.Text instead if you want only text from this cell.

It is perfectly worked. Thanx.
